# How to extract multiple patterns from a huge file, with repeating data blocks?

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file, which contains data as shown below.
Out of those multiple set of data, I  need to extract a specific data say `10238679000    C-73652 , 5123 & 23154, 25734`.This `C-73652` may/not be present in every set.

```
How can I achieve this through regex ? I feel, regex is the best option.
Or Is there any better approach for this ?
```

**test_file.txt**

```
Recieved request        #STARTS
Data getting generated for : "time":[10238679000]
.................   #CAN BE ANYTHING, BUT FEW LINES HERE
Starting data from 10238679000
A-123456 data 679720 for instance:  [1452]
C-73652 data 5123 for instance:  [23154, 25734]
B-967845 data 73421 for instance:  [37451]
G-809573 data 38456 for instance:  [92673]     #ENDS
Recieved request     #NEXT SET STARTS
may be same data as above or different data
In general it can have multiple set of such data
..............................   #CAN BE ANYTHING, BUT FRW LINES HERE
..............................
# SECOND SET ENDS
Recieved request  #REPEATS AGAIN
```

How can i resolve this through regex ?

Sample Output :

```
At 10238679000, C-73652 generated data of 5123 units with instance 23154, 25734
```

If `C-73652` present in another set, it should generate as above for that particular set of data.

Comment: Can you include a sample output? Or ```10238679000    C-73652 , 5123 & 23154, 25734``` is the output?

Comment: @kerwei i added sample output. let me know, if anything not clear.

Comment: What do you capture if ```C-73652``` is not present?

Comment: Regular expressions can allow you to quickly extract the data from the relevant line, but you still need to process the file and decide how to ouput the result, also when there is no data. Can you provide an example of what you've tried so far?

Comment: @Grismar tried this, Recieved request([^(]*) but this matches entire text. would like to extract those details based on each data block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a separate regex to match the title line, and store the begin time. Then, you can use a regex for each of the lines.

`Starting data from (\d*)` should work for the initial line

and `([A-Z]-\d*)?\s*data\s*(\d*).*:\s*\[([\d*, ]*)\]` for the data.

Driver Program(not the cleanest/best implementation, just used for demonstrating):

```
import re

test_data = """
Starting data from 10238679000
A-123456 data 679720 for instance:  [1452]
C-73652 data 5123 for instance:  [23154, 25734]
B-967845 data 73421 for instance:  [37451]
G-809573 data 38456 for instance:  [92673]     
data 38456 for instance:  [92673]
blah blah
Starting data from 121212
A-123456 data 679720 for instance:  [1452]
C-73652 data 5123 for instance:  [23154, 25734, 122121]]
B-967845 data 73421 for instance:  [37451]
G-809573 data 38456 for instance:  [92673]     
data 38456 for instance:  [92673]

"""

begin_rex = re.compile(r'Starting data from (\d*)')
line_rex = re.compile(r'([A-Z]-\d*)?\s*data\s*(\d*).*:\s*\[([\d*, ]*)\]')

current_time, match_line_rex = '', False
for line in test_data.splitlines():
    if not match_line_rex:
        begin = begin_rex.findall(line)
        if begin:
            current_time = int(begin[0])
            match_line_rex = True
    else:
        data = line_rex.findall(line)
        if data:
            data = list(data[0])
            data[2] = ' & '.join([dat.strip() for dat in data[2].split(',')])
            print '{}\t{}'.format(current_time, '\t'.join(data))
        else:
            match_line_rex = False
```

Output:

```
10238679000 A-123456    679720  1452
10238679000 C-73652 5123    23154 & 25734
10238679000 B-967845    73421   37451
10238679000 G-809573    38456   92673
10238679000     38456   92673
121212  A-123456    679720  1452
121212  C-73652 5123    23154 & 25734 & 122121
121212  B-967845    73421   37451
121212  G-809573    38456   92673
121212      38456   92673
```

Comment: can it be optimized ? say, can we handle it in single regex ? something like this "Recieved request([^(]*)"  , tried this but doesn't work as how i needed.

Comment: How exactly do you intend for it to work? Since you mentioned your file is quite large, it might actually be better to read it in chunks instead of in one go. If you want to read the whole chunk, you can combine both regexes
```Starting data from (\d*)|(?:^([A-Z]-\d*)?\s*data\s*(\d*).*:\s*\[([\d*, ]*)\])+``` In action [here](https://regex101.com/r/pOkKHj/2) . You can then process the match groups as you like

Comment: If line doesn't start with this unique ID A-123456 (example), then it shouldn't match that entire line. Line can be begin with unique ID as mentioned above or with some text like ESC

Comment: Starting data from (\d*)|(?:^([A-Z]-\d*)|(ESC)?\s*data\s*(\d*).*:\s*\[([\d*, ]*)\])+     ,
added ESC to regex. If line doesn't begin with Unique ID & ESC, then also it matches the rest of the line stuffs.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your question is unfortunately lacking some details . So, I took the liberty to make some assumptions. The following regex extracts, the second row for each of the data chunk. Group 1 captures `10238679000`, the time value, while group 2 captures `C-73652 data 5123 for instance:  [23154, 25734]`. I assumed that you only want to extract the row between the A and B lead characters.

`re.findall(r'(?:Starting data from )([\d]+)\nA-.*?\n(.*)\nB', test_file)`

Check it out in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/tZbJpm/1)

Comment: no, not between A and B. assume that C-73652 is some unique id.

Comment: @StackGuru The position is not fixed? In that case, how do you decide which one to extract? As long as the lead character is not either A, B or G?